# How to clone a webpage and its css elements and script?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been looking to try to clone a webpage, like say, Instagram's login page and its css elements and javascript locally.

Like, I want to copy and host the login page on my test server, all the while making it work normally as if it were connected to the internet.

I want the elements to be saved locally, so that I can run this test server without having to connect to the internet.

How do i achieve this?

P.S. - I know python and have tried a little bit of BeautifulSoup, but am not too good with it.

Comment: This question belongs on places like reddit and other forums. As you don't have code to solve.

Comment: @Dejan.S Nope, i don;t agree

Comment: You are looking for a recommendation and opinion based. You don't have any code you wrote for "web-scraping" or anything else that don't work. Read the rules about posting. Pretty clear there.

Comment: Over a year late, but for anyone wondering, it only shows the logo because Instagram's website is written in REACT. For those who don't know what that means, the entire website is rendered in the javascript code. The base HTML just loads the javascript bundles and executes it. In this case, the base HTML must be the instagram logo, and the javascript isn't running because of cross site scripting or something.

Answer (score 1):

You just try HTTrack ...

- HTTrack is a free and open-source Web crawler and offline browser
- HTTrack allows users to download World Wide Web sites from the
  Internet to a local computer.

More Reference to [Click](https://www.httrack.com/page/2/)

Comment: the page just stays on the instagram logo

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux or any flavour of linux then you can run this command.

```
wget www.websitename.com
```

If you are using windows machine then you need to install `wget` and configure it.

Here is help https://letswp.io/download-an-entire-website-wget-windows/

Comment: the page just stays on the instagram logo

Answer (score -1):

You can right mouse click on the page and choose Save As.. from the context menu. Dont't forget to Save as Type Web page complete. That's if you don't want to use other software. HTTTrack is a great option.
BeautifulSoup is just a web page scraping tool.

Comment: Nope, the page just stays on the instagram logo, doesn't move ahead to the login page. This seems to be a bot check or something

Comment: @Greatguy If you save the page you will get all you ask for. What does that even mean "the page just stays on the instagram logo"? You expect that you can login on your local machine and go to the real page?

Comment: @Greatguy, You get the css if you save the page, you have to unminify it and copy the classes you need, and inspect the elements to get the classes. This is a bit hard to do on this specific page because they use react, that is the reason there is no html when you save the page. In your case if you just want to copy the styles of the input boxes and its parent block just open up devtools and copy it from there, you got the html and css. Takes you about 15 minutes. There is no need to use tools and go through loops and spend 10+ hours. And watch the langugage and tone.

Comment: @Dejan.S i am sorry, been trying for 2 days and got nothing :( The  css classes?, well thanks a lot! i u wrote a answer, it would marked it as the answer to this question and again, sorry for the burst

Comment: @Greatguy With the Instagram it's a bit "complicated" if you don't know, I get it. I would do like this, open up the devtools and inspect whatever elements you need to get the css for, also if you right-click the parent element to what you want > edit as html, you can copy paste the full html for that specific part. Then get the css with inspect one element by one to get the css, like https://www.screencast.com/t/crKAgsJ2 (note that the css below can be related to that selected one)

Comment: @Dejan.S, I am trying this for an InfoSec seminar about phishing and stuff, but the page seems to be stuck at the Instagram logo. Thanks for taking the time anyway

Comment: @Greatguy can you please paste a screen on what you mean with stuck at the instagram logo?

Comment: I thought the question was closed. It would be helpful if you could modify the question, open it again and drop in a answer with an example of how you would do it. Thanks!